# Voicemeeter and Chrome Sound on Windows PC

Tags: google-chrome, audio, youtube, video-streaming, streaming

I need to mix the sound of my microphone with the a sound of youtube in my WEBRTC solution. To do this, i've used Voicemeeter until December 2022. After that, and the update of Chrome and maybe the update of Windows, I have a trouble to get the sound of Google Chrome. I don't know why, despite of the parameters that i've reviewed so many time.

I've used VB Cable to get the sound on Voicemeeter, I've tried OBS and I have reviewed all the parameter but nothing to do.

Maybe have you a solution to have the sound of my chrome navigator and the mic of the PC in output?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what trouble you're having... that sort of thing works fine for me...

Comment: what's your configuration exactly can you explain ? Thanks